# How to make live barcode reader using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I am using camera plugin https://pub.dev/packages/camera I want to take image stream from it and use it to identify the barcode using Firebase ml kit. Can I do that? I can't figure out how to take image stream from camera plugin and how to use this stream with ml kit. Can anybody help me? I am creating a live reader, I don't want to take picture using the camera plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some already built packages that you can use and enhance based on your use case like [barcode_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan).

However, I would encourage you to try a few things first and then turn to the community for help with the code that you have tried but didn't work.